# Azure data factory - SftpPermissionDeniedException

Tags: azure-data-factory, sftp

Using a copy data activity I want to upload files to an SFTP service, but receive the following error message:

[image]

I can upload files via a simple linux sftp client to the target folder with the same user, and also able to create files and folders within the target folder(but not in its parent folder, which is the root folder).
"Upload with temp file" option is set to false.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

To confirm which user your build runs as you can run the whoami command as a part of your build process.

Solution:

1. Store things inside of a folder that the user running the build has permissions to.
2. Change the ownership of the directory with the chown command before trying to write to it.

Refer - https://support.circleci.com/hc/en-us/articles/360003649774-Permission-Denied-When-Creating-Directory-or-Writing-a-File