# Azure Data Factory Permission Issue when copying to Parameterized Folder on SFTP Server

Tags: azure-data-factory

When copying to the ROOT folder on SFTP Server without any parameters as shown in the image the copy activity is successful. T
[image]

As you can see the file copies to the root no problems

[image]

However, when I try and copy to a dynamic folder (in this the dynamic folders are based on the time the copy activity happened) for example RAW\time_folder, see image, you can see there isn't any data in the folder.

[image]

[image]

When parameterizing the connection to a dynamic directory the configuration/parmeters are as follows:

[image]

[image]

The actual parameter to create the directory and send file to the directory is as follows:

```
@{pipeline().parameters.Zone}/@{pipeline().parameters.Time}
```

So, can someone let me know where the above parameters will successfully create the directory (in this case the dynamic time based directory), but not copy/send data to the directory?

Following the help I've received, I'm updating question with the error I'm getting after applying the suggestions, see below

[image]

The full error message is as follows:

```
ErrorCode=SftpPermissionDenied,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=Permission denied to access 'RAW/02-47/xxxxxxxx_20230613_20230613025522.csv.f95d11f792884fb888f7e535f0fb1a6e'.,Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.ClientLibrary.SftpConnector,''Type=Renci.SshNet.Common.SftpPermissionDeniedException,Message=Permission denied,Source=Renci.SshNet,'
```

The Expression for desTable is as follows:

```
@concat(
    pipeline().parameters.TableName,
    '_',
    formatDateTime(utcNow(),'yyyyMMdd'),
    '_',
    formatDateTime(utcNow(),'yyyyMMddhhmmss'), '.csv'
    )
```

[image]

Comment: This is a duplicate of your previous question and will be closed again for the same reason. This is a server configuration and ftp question and not a programming one.

Comment: This is not a duplicate. This question is about Azure Data Factory and its copy activity to an Azure SFTP Server. This would be totally wrong to close this question.

Comment: I agree my last question did concern the operation of an FTP application, software. This question is centred on the operation of Azure Platform services.

Comment: I have just discovered that this question is practically identical to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71955543/azure-data-factory-sftppermissiondeniedexception?rq=2 . In actual fact I'm getting the exact same error in Azure Data Factory ```Operation on target Copy to SFTP Server failed: ErrorCode=SftpPermissionDenied,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=Permission denied to access```

Comment: I have realised that I don't get SftpPermissionDenied when the folder is hardcoded. I get the SftpPermissionDenied when the folder is parameterized. Any thoughts why?

Comment: Try giving this expression `@concat(pipeline().parameters.Zone,'/',pipeline().parameters.Time)` as a value to Directory, instead of `@{pipeline().parameters.Zone}/@{pipeline().parameters.Time}`

Comment: @Aswin, thanks for getting in touch. I will try your suggestion once our systems are back up and running. In the meantime, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the value for dataset parameter is given as `@concat(pipeline().parameters.Zone,'/',pipeline().parameters.Time)` instead of `@{pipeline().parameters.Zone}/@{pipeline().parameters.Time}`, file is copied without error.

[image]

[image]

Update:

> If you receive the error "UserErrorSftpPathNotFound," "UserErrorSftpPermissionDenied," or "SftpOperationFail" when you're writing data into SFTP, and the SFTP user you use does have the proper permissions, check to see whether your SFTP server support file rename operation is working. If it isn't, disable the Upload with temp file (useTempFileRename) option and try again. To learn more about this property, see the preceding table. If you use a self-hosted integration runtime for the Copy activity, be sure to use version 4.6 or later.

**Reference:** [MS document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-sftp?tabs=data-factory) on Copy and transform data in SFTP server using Azure Data Factory or Azure Synapse Analytics

Comment: Did you face any error?

Comment: Hi @Aswin our systems are still down from yesterday  ... arrrgggggg .. crazy. Things should be back up and running in the next hour or so.. I will let you know. Thanks

Comment: Hi @Aswin, unfortunately you suggestion didn't work. I have updated the question with the error after applying your suggestion

Comment: Could you share the expression given for `@dataset().desTable`

Comment: Hi @Aswin, I have updated the question with the desTable expression. Thanks

Comment: Could you uncheck the `useTempFileRename` option in the sink dataset settings of copy activity and execute the pipeline

Comment: Hi @Aswin running the pipeline now without ```useTempFilleRename``` unchecked. Takes about 15mins to run

Comment: Hi @Aswin, with ```useTempFileRename``` unchecked I get the error ```SftpNetworkIssue,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=Meet network issue when connect to Sftp server 'xx,xx,xx,xx', SocketErrorCode: 'TimedOut'.,```

Comment: Sorry, @Aswin, I'm still getting the error ```ErrorCode=SftpPermissionDenied,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=Permission denied to access 'RAW/07-20/xxxxxxxx_20230613_20230613072241.csv'.,``` Not the previous error I mentioned.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254067/discussion-between-aswin-and-patterson).